# General Techniques for Locking or Synchronizing UI/Model/Disk for Cloud Support

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, thread-safety, deadlock

I'm implementing a ***cloud synchronization method in a shoebox application*** under Mac OS X Lion, and I'm (as expected) quickly running into threading/synchronization problems.

There are a number of components to the application, but I'm feeling a bit overwhelmed trying to prevent deadlocks while at the same time maintaining good separation between the pieces.

For example, my app has a few critical behaviors:

- Saves to disk periodically and when a model change occurs. *(To support Automatic/Sudden Termination under OS X Lion.)*
- Is periodically notified when a new serialized model is available on disk.
- Updates the UI when a model on disk is loaded into memory, or when notified of any model changes have been made that were not caused by user actions.

**Here's a sample use case that causes temporary brain hurt:**

1. User is viewing a list of model items in the application.
2. Simultaneously, application is notified of a new model on disk. Application loads the model into memory, storing into a temporary variable.
3. How can the application swap out the old hierarchical data model with the new one, without corrupting the UI thread? For example, there's a main **RootElement** object, with many **ChildElement** elements. If the UI thread is iterating over **myRootElement.children**, how can the **myRootElement** object be replaced without interfering? (Eg. mutating a list while being enumerated.)

More than a specific solution, I'm looking for any previous resources/techniques/paradigms to help design an app around this kind of concurrency and thread safety.

Comment: Is the problem really about locks or conflict resolution?

Comment: It's not about conflict resolution at all. The synchronization algorithm to compare two data models is solid, I just want to transform (what was last week) a single-threaded app to one that can properly handle model changes on a back-end thread, without deadlocking or producing an unstable/inconsistent interface.

Comment: Then your question should be "how to take a single threaded obj-c/cocoa app and safely multi-thread it", since the Cloud Support part is a red-herring.

Comment: I respectfully disagree - the purpose of mentioning cloud support was to note that there were processes other than the running application that could alter the data on disk. I know that this scenario isn't always restricted to cloud-based apps, but I feel it's more complicated than simply "multi-threading an app."

Answer (score 0):

The apple dev docs are pretty good on this subject.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html

You will need some `NSLock` knowledge, in particular. It seems NSLock is the nearest equivalent to a Mutex, or CriticalSection if you know those terms.